# How to calculate a point which minimizes total?

Tags: java, optimization, linear-programming, least-squares, simplex

I am trying to minimize the total sum of the ingredients.

For example, the total amount of vitamin A in A product and B product must exceed C. Also, the excess should be minimized.

I made 18 functions based on the data. (Vit, Carbohydrate, protein ~ etc )

I used apache simplexor to obtain a minimum value for each function.
(I added all functions to the constraints and calculated by adding each function to the objective function.)

I got the following [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UknHh.png), however, I want one point which minimizes the total of differences.(difference = min - C)

I am not good at English, I hope you understand my question.
Thank you for reading my question.

This is my code.

```
public class Simplex3D {
public static void cal(double[] a, double[] b, double[] c, double[] d) {
    //a, b, and c are the coefficient of functions 
    //d is the amount of ingredient that should be exceeded.
    System.out.println();
    Collection<LinearConstraint> constraints = new ArrayList<LinearConstraint>();
    constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] { 0, 1,0 }, Relationship.GEQ, 0));
    constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] { 1, 0,0 }, Relationship.GEQ, 0));
    constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] { 0, 0,1 }, Relationship.GEQ, 0));
    //x, y, z >=0
    constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] { a[5]*100, b[5]*100, c[5]*100 }, Relationship.GEQ, d[5]));
    constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] { a[16]*100, b[16]*100, c[16]*100 }, Relationship.GEQ, d[16]));
    constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] { a[4]*100, b[4]*100, c[4]*100 }, Relationship.GEQ, d[4]));
    for(int i=0;i<18;i++) {

    LinearObjectiveFunction f = new LinearObjectiveFunction(new double[] { a[i]*100, b[i]*100,c[i]*100 }, 0);
    // create and run the solver
    SimplexSolver solver = new SimplexSolver();
    //solver.optimize(f, constraints, GoalType.MINIMIZE, new NonNegativeConstraint(true));
    PointValuePair solution = solver.optimize(f, new LinearConstraintSet(constraints), GoalType.MINIMIZE, new NonNegativeConstraint(true));

    // get the solution
    double x = solution.getPoint()[0];
    double y = solution.getPoint()[1];
    double z = solution.getPoint()[2];
    double min = solution.getValue();
    double diff= min-d[i];

    System.out.println("x: "+x+" y: "+y+" z: "+z+" min: "+min+" diff: "+diff);
}
}
```

}

Comment: I am not able to understand your question. It would be better if you can give an example. For the 18 points you have used what is the answer you are expecting.

Comment: @AshraffAliWahab Thanks! To find the minimum value of each function under the constraint, the method I used was to obtain 18 points by calculating each function as a objective function and calculating it using the simplex method. But what I want to know is one point which meets all constraint and minimizes the sum of the differences. (key summary : 18 points-> 1 point)

Comment: I would suggest to first write down the mathematical model. Once you are happy with the model (and you are reasonably sure about its correctness), implement it in code using your favorite tool.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thank you! I'm trying to solve my problem using the ways you suggested, but it is hard to set mathematical models because I haven't been doing the math for too long :(

Answer (score 0):

> I made 18 functions based on the data.

So you've created 18 independent problems and solved them obtaining 18 solutions. This isn't the way to go.

Note that your problem has only three variables. This probably describes how a single product gets mixed, but you seem to have eighteen products. You have to describe all of them in the problem. Assuming 3 ingredients and 18 products, this means 3 * 18 variables in a *single* problem.

Only then, you can express an objective concerning the total of differences.

---

This may or may not help you. Anyway, you're having no programming problem. Instead, you're struggling with the problem formulation. Your LP problem sounds like a classical one, find something similar and find out how your LP differs.

Comment: Thank you! I have 3 products and 18 ingredients. I will mix 3 products. When combined, 18 ingredients must exceed a certain value each. It was difficult to apply to my problem with existing examples using simplex.